# How to evaluate the following limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{k=0}^n \left(1+\delta^{2^{k}}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

If $\delta \in ]0,1[$ then the following limit is :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{k=0}^n \left(1+\delta^{2^{k}}\right)$$
I tried to simplify the following product :
$$\begin{align} \prod_{k=0}^n \left(1+\delta^{2^{k}}\right)&= (1+\delta)(1+\delta^2)...\left(1+\delta^{2^{n}}\right)\\
\ln\left(\prod_{k=0}^n \left(1+\delta^{2^{k}}\right)\right) &=\sum_{k=0}^n \ln\left(1+\delta^{2^{k}}\right)
\end{align}$$
I couldn't really go far from here I tried the following :
$$0<\delta^{2^{k}}<1 \Leftrightarrow 0<\ln\left(1+\delta^{2^{k}}\right)<\ln(2)$$
But it seems useless.

Any idea to evaluate the product hence the limit ?

Answer (score 11):

Because it seems like you're asking for a *hint* more than a full answer, that's what I'll go for. Consider the first few partial products:

$$1 + \delta$$

$$(1 + \delta)(1 + \delta^2) = 1 + \delta + \delta^2 + \delta^3$$

$$(1 + \delta)(1 + \delta^2)(1 + \delta^4) = 1 + \delta + \delta^2 + \delta^3 + \delta^4 + \delta^5 + \delta^6 + \delta^7$$

I don't know about you, but I see a pretty striking pattern going on here, relating the infinite product to something that's much more familiar to me. The only thing missing is a proof that the pattern I'm seeing continues, which can be done using induction.

Comment: (+1) Great answer!

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(1-\delta)(1+\delta^{2^k})}{1-\delta}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1-\delta^{2^{n+1}}}{1-\delta}=\frac{1}{1-\delta}$$